# Laptop Backlight turms off after instaling intel vga drivers ( windows )

Tags: windows, intel, vga, backlight

uestion shifted to [superuser form](https://superuser.com/questions/955138/laptop-backlight-turms-off-after-instaling-intel-vga-drivers-windows)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. This website is for posting questions about specific problems encountered while developing software. Your question does not fall into this category, and would be better suited to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score -1):

I will advise you to roll-back the graphics adapter driver to the former one or download and install a driver update with an older date and version from the official ACER drivers download page...